# How do I prevent certain macros being run in a Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a reasonably complex group of scripts to perform a certain function for my work.  Due to the nature of the work, I have validated the code and have it locked down fairly tightly with passwords to prevent improper use/editing (the script is also locked down, but there are no problems with that for this query).  This all works well and if it ever has errors, it exits and re-protects the individual worksheets and the workbook.  All macros are run via buttons (actually just objects with macros assigned, not the older style coded buttons) on relevant worksheets and output is good.
However, this morning I discovered that the macros can still be run through the standard Macro screen (Alt + F8).  As I have a number of scripts in there that I use for development of updated versions, I want to disable this function.

I did a search for options and found UserInterFaceOnly, but it didn't work for my on Excel 2010 and I am led to believe that it may not be used in later versions.
Is there anyone who knows how to disable the ability for the user to run macros through the Alt + F8 Macro window, whilst allowing macros to be run that are assigned to objects within a worksheet?

The code that locks the worksheets/workbook is as follows:

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Cells.Locked = True
        ws.Protect Password:=strPWD
Next ws

ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:=strPWD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good solution using a different approach.  Rather than trying to lock the capability, I have used the 'Option Private Module' entry at the beginning of the module, meaning that the user never gets to see the macros that have been written.

This solution is an obvious one when you think about it, but having not used the Private Module option at all previously, it didn't initially occur to me.  Hopefully this answer to my own question will benefit some other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an old post, but in case someone finds it helpful.

Another way to accomplish this is to define your macros as Function instead of Sub. Sub Macros show in the Alt+F8 menu, Function Macros do not.